# Spring Security Custom filter overridden by basic http security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

Portion of applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/health"
                filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/swagger-ui.html"
                filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/images/**"
                filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/webjars/**"
                filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/v2/apidocs"
                filters="none" />               
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/*.ico"
                filters="none" />               
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="customAuthorizationFilter" />
        </security:filter-chain-map>
```

file: security-context.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/swagger-ui.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <http-basic/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="abc" password="Basicauth" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

There was custom filter to secure the method by authenticating request and checking the error.
After including the security-context.xml file ,for resource based security for a particular endpoint(swagger-ui.html) with user name and password.

After this security change the custom filter auth is not working,maybe overridden by new security implementation. How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

didn't have enough time to test it before putting up the answer but can you try creating your custom filter as below:

`<custom-filter ref="customAuthorizationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>`

I think it is about the precedence of the filters.